# Incrementing Individual Characters in String

Tags: c++, string

I dont know if I have the correct tiltle for this, so please correct me if I am wrong and I will change my title.

I have a string, for this example I will use:

```
"8ce4b16b"
```

I would like to shift the bits (I think) along 1 so the string would be:

```
"9df5c27c"
```

Any Ideas?

EDIT:

Just so you know, these strings are hex. So it will never reach z.
All I want to do is add a number to the numbers and progress one step through the alphabet so a->b, f->g ect ect

If the number is 9 there will be a condition to keep it as 9.

The output DOES NOT need to be a hex.

Also the string is only an example. It is part of an MD5 encryption.

Comment: With the specified example you don't shift any bits, you simply add 1 to every hexadecimal (I suppose) number in the string.

Comment: I do not understand the example. Every character is mapped to the next except '4'? What should happen with '9', 'Z' or `unsigned char(255)`?

Comment: @Peter G.: I guess that the 4 was a typo. I changed it to a 5.

Comment: Your edit makes no sense. If these are hex strings, F should never become G and 9 should always become A when adding 1.

Comment: If your strings are hex-strings, then you only have the values `0->9` and `A->F` since you're representing the base-10 values 0-15 ... there is no `G` value, and `0xF` wraps around to `0x0`.

Comment: @Dana @Jason Soryy bout that -- see new edit

Comment: @poixen: Seems like a very strange thing to do, but [my (edited) answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071709/incrementing-individual-characters-in-string/6071845#6071845) does exactly that.

Comment: An encryption scheme that encrypts both "8" and "9" as "9" will have some minor issues with decryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to increment each character in the string?
You can do that my iterating through the array and adding one to each character.

Comment: So I loop through each element in the string and add1? Will this work with chars too?

Comment: No, it's not as simple as this. Presumably the character is a hex value, so adding 1 to `f` returns `g` - which is incorrect or adding 1 to `9` - will not give you `a`! You need to handle the increment correctly...

Comment: @Nim the output doesnt not to be readable hex. So a 'g' is ok. I will have a condition to keep the 9 as a 9. So all I do is make m_string[i] += 1; ?

Answer (score 6):

Transform a `string`? This sounds like a job for [`std::transform()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

char increment(char c)
{
    if ('9' == c)
    {
        return '9';
    }
    return ++c;
}

std::string increment_string(const std::string& in)
{
    std::string out;
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out), increment);
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    assert(increment_string("8ce4b16b") == "9df5c27c");
    assert(increment_string("ffffffff") == "gggggggg");
    assert(increment_string("89898989") == "99999999"); // N.B: this is one of 2^8 strings that will return "99999999"
    assert(increment_string("99999999") == "99999999"); // This is one more. Mapping backwards is going to be tricky!
    return 1;
}
```

Any limits you wish to impose on the characters can be implemented in the `increment()` function, as demonstrated.

If, on the other hand, you wish to treat the string as a hexadecimal number and add `0x11111111` to it:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("8ce4b16b");
    long int i;
    iss >> std::hex >> i;
    i += 0x11111111;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::hex << i;
    assert(oss.str() == "9df5c27c");
    return 1;
}
```

No bits were shifted in the construction of this `string`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you simply added 0x11111111 to the integer. But can you specify precisely what tpye your input has? And what the result should be when you add one to "f" or "9"?

Comment: Yes, it really depends on whether you want to double the "hex number" or just alphabetically increment the char values. You don't have any 9's or F's in your example!

Answer (score 1):

That's not shifting the bits ... shifting a bit multiplies a word value by 2.  You're simply incrementing each hex value by 1, and that can be done by adding `0x11111111` to your dword.

For instance, if you took your value `0x8ce4b16b` (that would be treating the values you printed above as-if they were a 4-byte double-word in hexadecimal), shifting it by one bit, you would end up with `0x19C962D6`.

But if you simply want to increment each nibble of your dword (each individual value in a hex-number represents 4-bits or a nibble), you're going to have to add an offset of 0x1 to each nibble.  Also there is no value of `G` in a hex-word ... you have the values `0->9`, and then `A->F`, where `F` represents the base-10 value 15.  Finally, when you add `0x1` to `0xF`, you're going to wrap around to `0x0`.